# Solr web interface query with hyphen

Tags: solr, django-haystack, solr4

I have a schema created by haystack for indexing books and authors in Solr 4.3
When performing a search, all works fine except for search-terms including a hyphen.

I know you must escape them by using a backslash but even with the solr web interface i am not able to find the correct docs.

As illustrated in the screenshots below, there is an author named Ukiyo-E which can be found by using **full_name:(ukiyo)**. When entering **full_name:(ukiyo-e)** or **full_name:(ukiyo-e)**, i can't find anything.

[image: searching ukiyo gives one match Ukiyo-E]

EDIT

**Schema information:**

```
<fieldType name="edge_ngram" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="1">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" side="front" />
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
...
<field name="full_name" type="edge_ngram" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
```

**Analyser results:**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Analyze your term using the Analysis menu separately for indexing and querying. Specifically, you should have similar text processing routines during index and query time (see your full_name field in the schema). If you don't tokenize your query "ukiyo-e" into 2 terms `ukiyo` and `e`, but tokenize it during indexing, you will not be able to find the full term `ukiyo-e`.

Comment: Hi, tx for the response but ... i have lack of knowledge when it comes to solr ... i edit my post with analyzer results and schema definition of the field.

Comment: In `EdgeNGramFilterFactory` you set `minGramSize="2"`, after tokenizing "ukiyo-e" with `WordDelimiterFilterFactory` you have 2 tokens "ukiyo" and "e". The second token is only 1 character, but you require tokens to be minimum of 2 characters.

Comment: I suppose, you have `<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND" />` in your schema, which requires all the query terms present in the index. As your index does not have term `e` you cannot find this document, which has terms `uk`, `uki`, `ukiy` and `ukiyo` according to your schema.

Comment: Hi, many many thanks for the answer, I lowered the MinGram to 1 and the operator to OR and now the terms shows up. Thinking of setting up a local solr instance to play with the settings and analyse the results, I recon an MinGramSize of 1 creates a much bigger index...

Comment: You can remove the splitter `<filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>` from your analysis and set `minGramSize="2"` back. It depends, how you want to treat 1-character "words".

Comment: Don't think we have 1-character words... i'll remove it :-)
Thanks!